# Https keycloak does not start

Tags: docker, ssl, certificate, keycloak, ca

i'm tring to start a keycloak instance on an aws ec2 instance.
In particular i'm tring to deploy it with docker, i need this because we are more than 1 persone to work on it.

I bought an ssl certificate on https://sectigo.com/, and i would like to use it so secure this comunication.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder


ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true 
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true


ENV KC_DB=postgres

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

COPY keycloak-server.crt.pem /opt/keycloak/keycloak-server.crt.pem COPY keycloak-server.key.pem /opt/keycloak/keycloak-server.key.pem

ENV KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/opt/keycloak/keycloak-server.crt.pem ENV KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/opt/keycloak/keycloak-server.key.pem

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest 
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/


ENV KC_DB=postgres 
ENV KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=keycloakDB 
ENV KC_DB_URL_HOST=****** 
ENV KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432 
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=**** 
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=****** 
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost 
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

After i build the image i start it with this command:

```
docker run --name mykeycloak -p 8443:8443 -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=***** -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=**** mykeycloak start
```

But it gives me this error:

> 2023-03-27 23:24:27,150 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
> 2023-03-27 23:24:27,150 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Key material not provided to setup HTTPS. Please configure your keys/certificates or start the server in development mode.
> 2023-03-27 23:24:27,153 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.

Could anyone help me?

I expect to figure out with this problem, launching correctly the instance

Comment: You might be able to find the solution here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77520148/15838526) for Keycloak 22.0.5 in 2023.
In most of cases this should be a permission issue to private key or certificate file.  In this solution you will be able to use the `keycloak `along with `SSL` and `HOSTNAME `like `https://abc.xyz.com:8443` in `production mode`  without using `Nginx`

Answer (score 1):

Your `ENV KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=...` directive is only present in the build step of your docker image process. It needs to be moved to the block of `ENV` directives below the second `FROM`, in order to be present at runtime.

Unlike `KC_DB`, it is a pure runtime value, so it does not need to be present for the build step, only during runtime, so you don't need to copy it, just move it.